# c# foreach loop formatting

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have the following C# code that provide the below output but I need some help to change it to the below desire output. How can I rewrite my code to provide the "Required output"?

```
SearchResultSet results = session.Search(searchRequest);
results.GetCount());
IEnumerable columns = results.GetColumns();
while (results.HasNext())
{
    foreach (string column in columns)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(column + ": " + results.GetString(column));
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Output:

```
Unique_ID: 234556
Address: 555 John Street
City: Orlando
State: FL
Zip: 32751
Unique_ID: 5326536
Address: 1200 Avenue of America
City: New York
State: NY
Zip: 10016
Unique_ID: 4815585
Address: 149 Madison Avenue
City: New York
State: NY
Zip: 10016
```

Required Output:

```
Unique_ID|Address|City|State|Zip
234556|555 John Street|Orlando|FL|32751
5326536|1200 Avenue of America|New York|NY|10016
4815585|149 Madison Avenue|New York|NY|10016
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it reads like a homework assignment

Comment: my initial question would be this @zXSwordXz who wrote the original code..? why can't you edit the code yourself.. unless you can't read and or understand the current code.. what does the code output currently.. also it would be helpful if you could show the sql query or example of what the source file looks like.. this is a poor example of a question also if you don't know how to append a `|` at the end of the column names.. in all due respect perhaps you shouldn't be coding.. also you could implement the string.Join method.. do some more research and show more effort on your part

Comment: Wow...you guys are brutal to beginners. Anyway, it is not homework. @methodman, it is not coming from sql, the data is coming from an API.  In any case, you're right, I should have don't more work.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm, I haven't tested it. I hope it helps you. I would do it using two `foreach` inside the main `while`

```
SearchResultSet results = session.Search(searchRequest);
 results.GetCount()); 
 IEnumerable columns = results.GetColumns();
 bool printColumns = true;
        while (results.HasNext())
        {
            if(printColumns){
                foreach (string column in columns)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}|", column)); //Will print Unique_ID|Address|etc...
                }               
            }
            printColumns = false;
            foreach (string column in columns)
            {
                Console.Write(String.Format("{0}|", results.GetString(column))); //Will print 234556|555 JOHN STREET|Orlando|FL|32751
            }           
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
```

**EDIT:**

The previous code keeps a pipe at the end of the strings. If you don't want this, you should use a `String` variable, concatenate the result, and after each `foreach`, you simply do a susbtr to remove the ending pipe.

Comment: It's arguably not necessary to say "Edit" in this case.  Just make the necessary changes. :)

Comment: You can also have a `bool` set to false then in the `foreach` write the pipe before the value if the `bool` is true and set it to true at the end of the loop.  That way the pipes are only between the values.